# Using a 16A energy monitor in a 10A socket

Tags: electrical, energy-audit

I'm in Australia (220-240 / 50-60Hz) and wanting to monitor some appliances energy usage. The sockets here are 10Amp standard.

Am I going to run into dire trouble if I use a 16A monitoring device between the 10A Wall socket and the devices (10Amp and under) that I plug into the monitoring device?

The concern is because the monitoring device specs say it's Max output current is 16A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When electrical appliances talk about Amperes it usually means

- how much max POWER it can OUTPUT
- or
- how much max POWER it can MEASURE

In your case, the spec actually means not to exceed the 16A limit.

So if you are monitoring a 10A socket that is well under the spec. So you will be fine.

As long as you do not exceed the 16A monitoring device limit you will be OK.

Usually in home applications.. you *will(should)* never actually have anything even close to that 16A limit. Power leads are typically marked 16A maximum to conform to electrical and home safety standards.

[image]

16A X 220Volt = 3500Watts

You will only see devices use more than that in Industrial situations and usually run of multiple phase supplies and massive core cables.